# Emailed image included in email message is different when the receiver replies

Tags: mail.app, email

*(That title is rather garbled but I don't know a better way to describe it)*

I email with someone who uses a PC – I don't know what OS version or email program he uses. I'm using OSX 10.11.6. Recently I've sent a few images in a couple of emails using Apple Mail. When my friend replies he includes the whole message including any attached images (not my preferred email etiquette but whatever).

The issue is that some of the images in his reply are different than the ones I've sent! In one email I included two images and in his reply one image was right and the other was wrong. In all cases the "wrong" image is the one below of... a danger marker?

At first I wondered if the correct images were getting through but they seem to be (or at least he hasn't said "why the heck are you sending me a danger marker..."?

Is this a case of his email program being stupid about attachments?

[image]

Comment: Did you ask him what he's seeing or if anyone else that he emails sees the wrong picture? Have you done a Google Images search for that image to see more info about that particular picture? Also what email providers do you both use, and can you find out what software he uses?

Comment: @kal-al - I didn't ask but I could tell from his responses that he was seeing he images I sent (I certainly wondered about that initially). I did a Goggle reverse image search and it came up empty: not a duplicate of an image Goggle knows about. I winder what will happen if I send him the "wrong" image? 

Comment: Weird... Can you find out his OS, email client, and tell us your email server and his email server? (E.g. Is he on gmail.com and you're on icloud.com in which case I wouldn't see how they'd e at fault, or is he on some not well known third party one which may be somehow messed up?) Just to rule your your mail client by the way can you view his email response on webmail just to see how it looks? And can you ask him to view his software and his webmail "sent" folders to see how it looks in there?